# Am I making a reference cycle?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, when defining functions in a scope, are they keeping strong references to variables in outside scope? Sorry, I'm not sure how to properly ask this.

Below code might be a better explanation:

```
var map = new Map();

function addToMap(id, data) {
    map.set(id, data);

    Object.defineProperty(data, "$$self", {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        get: function() {
            // Am I creating a ref cycle here?
            return map.get(id);
        },
    });
}

function init() {
    var data = { name: "data" };
    addToMap(1, data);
    data.$$self; // NOTE: "run" the getter somehow
}

init();    
map.delete(1);
```

Is `data` going to be released or not?

Is there a leak now (or rather after garbage collection)?

Is `data` holding a strong reference to `map`?

How can I test this or check if a leak might happen? Can I do it in the Web Inspector?